Does VerneMq broker publish the same message 2 times to a topic if the routing score is 80/20?
I have VerneMq Cluster of 8 nodes, 1 node always has a routing score of 80/20. Other 7 nodes have routing score of 99/1.
I also have a device client publisher and server subscriber. Device client publishes to a topic, my servers(4 in count) are subscribed to the shared topic.
Since VerneMq has a concept of shared subscription where, if more than one server is subscribed to the same topic then only one server gets the message.
For Eg: Device publishes to topic
/foo/bar/xyz
Servers are subscribed to shared topic
$share/foo/bar/#
Problem :
I am seeing 2 message publishes in my log with same message id.
Is it possible the routing score of 80/20 can cause this duplicate message publish?

Are you publishing to the exact same topic as as the subscribers? Normally share subscriptions have a prefix appended, but the publish is to the bare topic (e.g. publish to foo/bar and subscribe to $shared/group/foo/bar )

The device publishes to is /foo/bar/xyz. Servers are subscribed to $share/foo/bar/#
Device uses paho mqtt client library
@hardillb

Topics should not start with a leading /
